# How can I change the visibility of an item inside Simple Cursor Adapter that not comes from "to" parameter

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I have a SimpleCursorAdapter that contains some textViews and ImageViews his structure is this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImgViewIconFoodList"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_spice" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImgViewIconFoodList"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtViewFoodCategoryList"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Category"
                    android:textColor="#949494"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtViewFoodNameList"
                    style="@style/foodListText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgAddedCart"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                android:visibility="invisible"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_verified_symbol" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I'm populating most of items (textviews,imgviews,etc... ) are from a db and works well when are in parameters "from" and "to" in the SimpleCursorAdapter creation.

But my problem is when I need to acces to the (ImageView) id/imgAddedCart .

This ImageView is not in the "to" parameter but i need to interactuate with this. 
I wanna change his poperty visibility in function of a condition(if

> (id_alimento == codigo))

but i can't do this because I don't know how to acces to this item.

Can someone help me ?

lots of thanks.

```
String[] from = new String[]{MyDBAdapter.KEY_NOMBRE,MyDBAdapter.KEY_CAT,MyDBAdapter.KEY_ID_CAT};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.txtViewFoodNameList,R.id.txtViewFoodCategoryList,R.id.ImgViewIconFoodList};

    private void fillData() {

        //obtain all codes for principal cursor
        myCursor = mDBHelper.fetchAllCodes();

        //obtain all codes for other cursor to compare with principal
        myShoppingListCursor = mDBHelper.fetchShoppingList();


        getActivity().startManagingCursor(myShoppingListCursor);

        getActivity().startManagingCursor(myCursor);


        SimpleCursorAdapter codes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(rootView.getContext(),R.layout.row,myCursor,from,to,0);

        codes.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
                int viewId = view.getId();
                String id_alimento = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));

                if (myShoppingListCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
                    do {
                        String codigo = myShoppingListCursor.getString(myShoppingListCursor.getColumnIndex("id_alimento"));
                        if (id_alimento == codigo){

                            // HERE I WANNA CHANGE THE @+id/imgAddedCart visibility property to Visible

                        }
                    } while(myShoppingListCursor.moveToNext());
                }
                if (viewId == R.id.txtViewFoodNameList) {((TextView) view).setText(cursor.getString(columnIndex)); }
                if (viewId == R.id.txtViewFoodCategoryList){((TextView) view).setText(cursor.getString(columnIndex));};
                if (viewId == R.id.ImgViewIconFoodList){
                    icName = "ic_oil";
                }

                    Context c = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                    int id = c.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/"+icName, null, c.getPackageName());
                    ((ImageView) view).setImageResource(id);
                }
                return true;
            }});
        lv.setAdapter(codes);
    }
```

Comment: so add it to `to` array and instead of using `ViewBinder` (which is preferred when you have views other than `TextView` / `ImageView`) you can override `SCA#setViewImage(ImageView v, String value)` method

Comment: what codigo  is returning ?

Comment: @pskink sorry, I don't understand you, can you explain it better or code and example ? , thanks

Comment: add your `ImageView` id to `to` array and make custom `SimpleCursorAdapter` by overriding `setViewImage` method: `class SCA extends SimpleCursorAdapter { ...`

Comment: @pskink it wok's perfect i create a custom Cursor Adapter an it works !!!

Comment: not custom `CursorAdapter` - create a custom `SimpleCursorAdapter` - its much easier